# How to pass environment variables in ansible

Tags: ansible, winrm

I am using `winrm` in ansible to communicate with my windows server. I am trying to create directory its passing in Trail-1 (when I am using raw-powershell) but its failing in win_file.

Can any help me how to pass environment variable to ansible windows tools (win_file or win_copy)....

Trail-1

```
- name:   Create the directory
  raw: powershell  mkdir $ENV:ProgramFiles\ravi
```

Trail-2

```
- name: Create the  directory
  win_file: path= "$ENV:ProgramFiles\ravi" state=directory
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$ENV` variable is read from the local machine, not the remote instance, right? If yes then, according to the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-access-shell-environment-variables), you can write:

Trail-1:

```
- name:   Create the directory
  raw: "powershell  mkdir {{ lookup('env', 'ProgramFiles') }}\ravi"
```

Trail-2:

```
- name: Create the  directory
  win_file: path= "{{ lookup('env', 'ProgramFiles') }}\ravi" state=directory
```

Comment: Thanks for your responds. but using powershell (raw) Trail-1 is working. I want with win_files....

Comment: Generally speaking, it's better that you elaborate on "it's not working".  What is the value of `{{ lookup('env', 'ProgramFiles') }}` at the time the command is run? What error message are you having?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the format that needs to be used to create a directory using win_file in a Ansible Playbook...

```
---
- name: Create temp directory
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Create temp directory
      win_file:
        path: C:\temp\test_1
        state: directory
```

Comment: I want to crate a directory with generic path (i.e without using C:/)